# Docker-compose flask app not printing output from 'print'

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a flask app that has one route and nothing complex going on, running in a docker container. I cannot for the life of me get print statements to show up in the logs (`docker-compose logs -f <containername>`). So far, I have tried various answers that supposedly have fixed this problem for others including:

1. Calling `print("test", flush=True)`
2. Setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` and verifying it is set in the actual container with `echo`
3. Setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0`
4. Running python with the `-u` flag
5. Using the logging module (logger.warning, logger.info, etc)

So far nothing has worked. The flask app is starting perfectly fine, but no output from my print statements is shown. I have sanity checked that i'm editing the correct file by adding random syntax errors and watching the app brick itself. I'm using python 3.8 and docker-compose 2

Comment: Can you please provide you Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and py files? Also can you try docker-compose up <service> and check if it prints when you send requests to Flask?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide those files as they are on an isolated network. It does in fact print stuff when I send requests to flask, just not when I put print statements in the main() call

Answer (score 3):

I found this question while looking for answers to a similar problem. I was running a flask app in a conda environment in a container and wasn't getting any log output even though the flask app itself was working fine. I added the following lines to my Dockerfile and it starting logging as expected -

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN echo "source activate my_env" > ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/my_env/bin:$PATH

CMD ["python", "api.py"]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys
print('It is working',file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Did not work unfortunately. Restarted container and still no output

Answer (score 1):

You can see logs with docker-compose or docker

With docker-compose you have to see SERVICE

```
Note: you add containername but you have to add service name
NOT $ docker-compose logs -f <containername> 

USE $ docker-compose logs -f <SERVICE_NAME>)
```

With docker you have to add container name or container id

```
docker logs -f CONTAINER_ID | CONTAINER_NAME
```

Comment: Docker-compose logs does not show the print statements

Comment: did you add container id or service name end of the docker-compose logs command ?